# Highcharts Treemap Tile Name Blocking Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, highcharts

I have a Highcharts treemap with an id name for each main tile:

```
{
  id: '<%= datum['name'] %> - <%= datum['name'] %>',
  name: '<%= datum['name'] + "-" + datum['name'] %>'
},
{
    name: '',
    parent: '<%= datum['name'] %> - <%= datum['name'] %>',
    value: <%= datum['high_risk'] %>,
    color: "#ed6d00",
    className: 'risks <%= datum['id'] %>'
}, {
    name: '',
    parent: '<%= datum['name'] %> - <%= datum['name'] %>',
    value: <%= datum['low_risk'] %>,
    color: "#2acdc6",
    className: 'risks <%= datum['id'] %>'
}, {
    name: '',
    parent: '<%= datum['name'] %> - <%= datum['name'] %>',
    value: <%= datum['moderate_risk'] %>,
    color: "#ffe80a",
    className: 'risks <%= datum['id'] %>'
}
```

Each main tile is made up of 3 inner tiles. I'm using AJAX so when any of the inner tiles are clicked, I show a modal view. The issue I'm having is the name on the main tile is blocking the click. When I click on the name, nothing happens. Is there a way to make the click work on the name as well as the tiles? Or is there a way to have the click pass through the name so the click registers on the main tile?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case on some online editor with sample data which I could work on?

Comment: @SebastianWędzel Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shawnpk/L3m0659g/8/. You can see that you can click on the colored boxes, but not the title.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good approach will be to implement this functionality inside the **click series event** or maybe even better to use click callback on particular point for your case.

Demo for series click: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/mjb9pc0L/

Code:

```
events: {
  click(e) {
    console.log("industry click");
    e.preventDefault();
            console.log(e)
    var industryId = (e.target).className.baseVal.split(' ')[2];
    console.log(industryId);

    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: 'https://www.google.com',
      dataType: 'script',
      success: function(result) {
        console.log("success!!");
        console.log(result);
        //eval(result);
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("error!!");
      }
    });
  }
},
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.events.click

API for point click event: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.treemap.point.events.click

Comment: This works on the tile, but still not on the name attribute. I think the problem is this line: `(e.target).className.baseVal.split(' ')[2];`. What I'm doing is adding a `className` (which is the id) to each tile and using that to redirect to another view by pulling the `id` out of the `className` list. The `name` attribute doesn't have that id in a `className` list, so I think that's why it isn't working. Is there a way I can add a `className` to the entire main tile and click anywhere in that main tile (including the name) to redirect?

Comment: So as I mentioned above maybe the point.events.click will be a better solution for your case? In this callback this represents the point and you will have a better access to the point properties. See: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7tw0gL53/